# How to change an attribute value with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm newbie with rspec and I'm facing some problems with it. Could someone help me?

I have a controller action responsible for deactivate an user. I'm trying to cover it with rspec tests, but the result is not what I'm waiting for.

Controller:

```
def deactivate
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if !@user.nil?
    @user.update_attribute(:active, false)
    redirect_to users_url
  end
end
```

Controller Spec

```
describe "PUT #deactivate" do
  describe "with valid parameters" do
    before (:each) do
      @user = mock_model(User, :id => 100, :login => "login", :password => "password123",
                               :email => "email@gmail.com", :active => true)
      User.should_receive(:find).with("100").and_return(@user)
    end

    it "should deactivate an user" do
      @user.stub!(:update_attribute).with(:active, false).and_return(true)
      put :deactivate, :id => "100"
      @user.active.should eq false
    end
  end
end
```

The test result:

```
1) UsersController PUT #deactivate with valid parameters should deactivate an user
   Failure/Error: @user.active.should eq false

   expected: false
        got: true

   (compared using ==)
```

So, I don't understand why the active attribute stills true when it should be false. Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Comment: what is `stub!` method? can you remove the line of `@user.stub...`?

Comment: Kien, thanks for the reply.
However, it stills not working

Comment: I posted my answer, can you try it?

Comment: Sure. But, no success =/

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be stubbing the update_attribute method unnecessarily. Try removing that line and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry! It's not working. When I removed this line, another problem was risen:

1) UsersController PUT #deactivate with valid parameters should deactivate an user
     Failure/Error: put :deactivate, :id => "100"
       Mock "User_100" received unexpected message :update_attribute with (:active, false)

Comment: So you removed this entire line """@user.stub!(:update_attribute).with(:active, false).and_return(true)""", or did you just remove the ".stub!" bit?

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation is "wrong".

Let's see what happens when your spec `it "should deactivate an user"` is executed:

1. `@user.stub!(:update_attribute).with(:active, false).and_return(true)` modifies the existing mock model, so it has an `update_attribute` which, when called with arguments `:active` and `false`

   1. will return `true`
   2. will keep track that this call has happened (that's what mocks do)
   3. (and, unlike a real `User` object, **will do nothing else**)
2. `put :deactivate, :id => "100"` calls the real `deactivate` in your Controller
3. Your Controller calls `User.find`. But you've mocked that class method, which will return the mock object `@user` instead of searching for the actual user with that `id`.
4. Your Controller calls `@user.update_attribute`. But because of step 3 above, `@user` here is the mock object, too. Its `update_attributes` method is the one from step 1. As we've seen above, it will return true, keep track that this call happened and **do nothing else**. Which means it will **not** change `@user`'s `active` attribute, so that stays `true`.

Changing `active` when `update_attribute` is called is functionality of objects of the actual `User` class, but no such object came into play while running your spec. Because this functionality is inherited from `ActiveRecord`, you don't have to test it. Instead just test that the `update_attribute` has been received by the mock object:

```
    it "should deactivate an user" do
      @user.stub!(:update_attribute).with(:active, false).and_return(true)
      put :deactivate, :id => "100"
      @user.should have_received(:update_attribute).with(:active, false)
    end
```

(I'm guessing about the old `should` syntax here, based on [how it's done with the newer `expect` syntax](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-1/docs/verifying-doubles/using-an-object-double#doubling-a-constant-object).)

### To mock or not?

If you *do* want to test the combined functionality of your controller *with the actual `User` implementation*, do not mock `User` or its objects. Instead test from the browser perspective with a [request spec](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec). (It might make sense to do that *additionally*, even if you want the isolated tests for only controller (with model mocked) and for only model (which probably won't require doubles, except maybe for other models).

Answer (score 0):

I look for this for a long time,  [`update_column`](http://www.davidverhasselt.com/set-attributes-in-activerecord/)  can always work no matter  you use `let` or `build`

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this:

```
describe "should deactivate an user" do
  before do
    @user.stub!(:update_attribute).with(:active, false).and_return(true)
    put :deactivate, :id => "100"
  end
  it { @user.active.should eq false }
end
```

Comment: Not working too:    
    1) UsersController PUT #deactivate with valid parameters should    deactivate an user 
     Failure/Error: it { @user.active.should eq false }
       
       expected: false
            got: true
       
       (compared using ==)

Comment: @hugalves how about `and_return(false)`?, or try change in your old code.

Comment: I tried both. No success. I think that I will have to use FactoryGirl. I'm giving up of using mock_model in this case =/

Comment: yes, i think so, FactoryGirl help you easier and less painful when do something like this.

Answer (score -2):

when you are mocking the call to `update_attribute`, how is the model going to change?

if you are a beginner: DONT use stubs and mocks!

first get a general knowledge in testing, THEN expand your knowledge to mocks and stubs.

Comment: I thought I should mock the :update_attribute method too, like the :find one.

I had searched a lot before had been added this question and I guess that you should help me more explaining why I was wrong or adding some good tutorials for me and other begginners ..